# Getting two indexes for which maximum is reached

Tags: r, indexing

I have problem with getting two indexes in output for which we have maximum. Let's consider code following.

```
choose_coef<-function(vec){
  t<-seq(from=1,to=2,by=0.5)
  for (i in 1:length(t)){
    for (j in 1:length(t)){
    vec<-append(vec,i/2-j/2)
    }
  }
#which i,j gives max(vec) 
}
```

And what I want to get in output is : The maximum is for i=... and j=.... However I found it not so easy to do. It's easy to extract one index for which we have maximum, but the problem occurs when we have two indexes. Is there any simple solution how can we do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why you are passing a vector to this function then appending stuff to the end of it. I'm guessing you want `vec` to be empty.

A simple solution would be a modification like this:

```r
choose_coef <- function() {
  t <- seq(from = 1, to = 2, by = 0.5)
  vec <- numeric()
  for (i in 1:length(t)){
    for (j in 1:length(t)){
    vec <- append(vec, setNames(i/2 - j/2, paste0("i=", i, ";j=", j)))
    }
  }
  names(which.max(vec))
}
```

Which produces:

```r
choose_coef()
#> [1] "i=3;j=1"
```

Alternatively, the following function is self-describing, in that when run it outputs an explanation of how it works:

```r
choose_coef <- function() {
  t <- seq(from = 1, to = 2, by = 0.5)
  vec <- numeric()
  for (i in 1:length(t)){
    for (j in 1:length(t)){
    vec <- append(vec, i/2 - j/2)
    }
  }
 cat("The maximum value was", max(vec), "which occurred at position",
     which.max(vec), "\nSince there were", length(t), 
     "iterations of j for each of the", length(t), 
     "iterations of i,\nwe know that the maximum occurred on:\ni =", 
     (which.max(vec) - 1) %/% length(t) + 1, "and j =",
     (which.max(vec) - 1) %% length(t) + 1)
}
```

So we just do:

```
choose_coef()
#> The maximum value was 1 which occurred at position 7 
#> Since there were 3 iterations of j for each of the 3 iterations of i,
#> we know that the maximum occurred on:
#> i = 3 and j = 1
```